# In UIKit we can set label.numberOfLines = 0 when we do not know how many lines the text will take? What is the alternative of this in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to know the alternative of label.numberOfLines in SwiftUi.

I have used Text(message).lineLimit(0) but it does not work.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var message = "This is a very big sentence to print in single line."
    var body: some View {
        Text(message).lineLimit(0)
                .font(.largeTitle).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `0` to `nil` as `Text(message).lineLimit(nil)`

Answer (score 3):

You should Change `Text(message).lineLimit(0)` to `Text(message).lineLimit(nil)`